# Convert int column to double in LINQ - functiom addHours

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, double

I set the LinqDataSource Where caluse with:

```
LinqDataSource1.Where ="StartDate.Value.AddHours((double)TimeLimitHour) < DateTime.Parse(\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\")";
```

I want to add `TimeLimitHour` column (`int` type) to `StartDate` column (`DateTime` type) and I need to convert TimeLimitHour to double type.
How can I do it???

Comment: Any chance you could change the design so you can use a *real* LINQ query specified in code rather than specifying it as a string?

Comment: Not so, It's a bit complicated